# How to calculate time duration between Logintime and logouttime in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
`Session["LogOutTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lbllogintime1.Text = Session["LogInTime"].ToString();
        lbllogouttime1.Text = Session["LogOutTime"].ToString();
        lblduration1.Text = "";`

       //I have created two session for login and logout and store the time in session
```

// I also created one label called duration to find difference between Login time and logout time to store the value.I don't Know how to calculate the duration between Login time and Logout time.so please help me to find the duration.

Comment: `TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime`.

Comment: You can save in session any kind of object, then make a simple subtraction between `Session["LogOutTime"]` and `Session["LogInTime"]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing the login and logout strings back into DateTime objects and subtracting one from the other to end up with a TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(Session["LogOutTime"]) -
  DateTime.Parse(Session["LogInTime"]);
```

Comment: If they are stored as DateTime, don't parse; cast.

Comment: I was assuming they were stored as strings because of this line: "Session["LogOutTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();"

Comment: Yeah OP should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

use `TimeSpan` which Represents a time interval

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(Session["LogOutTime"]) -  DateTime.Parse(Session["LogInTime"]);
```

for more information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.100).aspx